# How to detect tap (or any other gesture event) on Positioned widget on another widget in CustomScrollView?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, overflow, z-index, customscrollview

Here is a widgets tree:

```
CustomScrollView(Clip.none)
  SliverList
    Column
      HourItem
        SizedBox
          Stack
            Positioned(top: 30)
```

The result is:
[image: Flutter overflow screenshot]

I can handle tap area where blue arrow is point on, and can't where red arrow.

If it would be web I would use `z-index` property, but how can I do the same in Flutter?

Answer (score 0):

use `GestureDetector`

```
Positioned(top: 30,child: GestureDetector(
                      child:  SomeWidget(),
                      onTap: () {
                        // some action 
                      },
                    ),),
```